# Microsoft Flow Contact On-Premises Website

Tags: azure, power-automate

I'd like to make a Microsoft Flow workflow in the cloud use an on-premises website.

I'm beginning to think it's not possible.

To begin testing, I setup a simple flow based on a recurrence.

Each recurrence, it tries to access a website on my local HTTP website on my domain using an HTTP step.

I've setup an on-premises data gateway on local machine and in the azure portal, but have no way of associating that with a flow or HTTP step.

Microsoft documentation says the data gateways don't support HTTPs traffic, so I made sure I had a working HTTP binding for the site.

I'm not sure if I could design a custom connector for HTTP or not.  This is not a web api, this is just a standard unsecured website behind my firewall that has some company related data on it.

It seems to me like I shouldn't be the only one wanting to do this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Currently you cannot do that directly. How about exposing your on-premise HTTP Endpoint via [Azure Relay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-relay/relay-what-is-it) or some other technology.

There is, however, an [On-Premises Data Gateway for Microsoft Flow](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/gateway-reference/) (which internally uses Azure Service Bus). This **!! currently !! (2017-07-24) !!** supports the following data sources:

- SQL Server
- SharePoint
- Oracle
- Informix
- Filesystem
- DB2